# php: unexpected behaviour iterating through array

Tags: arrays, foreach

i'm trying to iterate through an array as follows:

```
$data = array(
    "i0" => "item 0",
    "i1" => "item 1",
    "i2" => "item 2",
    "i3" => "item 3",
    "i4" => "item 4",
    "i5" => "item 5"
);


foreach($data as $id=>$capt);
{
    echo $id.": ".$capt."<br>";
}
```

i'm expecting getting 6 elements, but the foreach loop will only output the last item. any ideas why?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error is in `foreach($data as $id=>$capt);`, it should not have a `;` at the end. Remove it and the loop will work.